# Getting access_token from adal.js (browser side) to access graph.windows.net or graph.microsoft.com

Tags: angular, adal.js

i'm writing an angular 5 application using the package adal-angular4 ( which is updated to work with angualr 5) as an adal wrapper library.

The authentication works perfectly, but when i try to get an access_token for azure graph api , or graph microsoft i get only a timeout error.

this is the relevant code i'm using:

```
init(): void {

this.adalConfig = {
    tenant: this.configService.get("tenant"),
    clientId: this.configService.get("clientId"),
    endpoints: {
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "https://graph.windows.net/": "https://graph.windows.net"
    }
};

this.adalContext = adalLib.inject(this.adalConfig);

this.adalService.init(this.adalConfig);
this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
//this.adalService.userInfo;    
}

getAzureGraphAccessToken2(): Observable<any> {
let result = new Subject<string>();
this.adalContext.acquireToken('https://graph.windows.net/', (mess, token) => {
    if (token) {
    result.next(token);
    }
});
return result.asObservable();
}

getAzureGraphAccessToken(): Observable<any> {
let result = new Subject<string>();

this.adalService.acquireToken("https://graph.windows.net/").subscribe(token => {
    if (token) {
    result.next(token);
    }
});
return result;
}
```

I've written two implementations of the code to get the token, one using the adalService wrapper from the adal-angualr4 package, and one instantiating directly the adal context, in both case i end up with a null token.

In the direct implementation (getAzureGraphAccessToken2()) i also get this timeout message from adal "Token renewal operation failed due to timeout"

Any suggestion?

Best regards,
Michele

Comment: Can you please show the full error message?

Comment: actually, i've found out it's a compatibility issue between last adal.js release and adal-angular4 wrapper...using adal.js 1.0.15 and adal-angular4 1.1.11 all works fine...